# Persisting a subset of Core Data objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, cocoa, core-data

This is a little strange, but I want to store an array of `NSManagedObjects` outside of Core Data.

Core Data is managing all of my model's properties and relationships. One such relationship is to all of an `Author`'s `Books`. Sometimes it is useful to know that same list in a certain order, so I have added `booksByDate` (for example) to the `NSManagedObject` Author.

Because the sort descriptor proved expensive, I implemented a cache, using an iVar on `Author`. This helped a lot with some laggy UI issues I was experiencing. But the cache was only useful after it was first loaded, so when my application launches, I now go and tell each `Author` to cache its `booksByDate`. This adds a few seconds to my launch time, but drastically speeds up the performance once the app is running.

I would like to reduce that launch time. One area I am experimenting with is somehow storing each `Author`'s cached `booksByDate`. At launch, instead of telling each `Author` to generate its cache using the expensive sort descriptor, I could just pass out each stored cache to it's correct `Author`.

How might I store these caches so they persist between executions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option would be to have a index member for each book.
When you insert a new book , just loop through the book's author list of books and set the appropriate value for that book's index.
This way , every time you ask for the books , you can sort based on that index. 
That will be much faster than comparing by date.

Comment: That's interesting - I hadn't considered that it was the Date part that was having the impact - I assumed it was any sort descriptor. I will give it a try. It would still be interesting to know if what I proposed in my question is possible, though.

Comment: I'm investigating the 'Indexed' option in XCode's Core Data editor - scouting for imformation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022065/indexing-a-core-data-property-to-improve-nssortdescriptor-performance

Comment: Indexing would be an improvement but I guess you are not adding the books in a chronological order. So you still have to order them. Of course the Date comparison is far more expensive than a simple int comparison.

Comment: Even if I add them in chronological order, there's nothing to say I won't want them in a different order later, and experience the same issues. I am going to try managing the index myself as outlined in your answer.